# resizing images for iphone and ipad resolutions

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage, image-scaling

I'm about to start a new iphone/ipad project which required a library of images. I've been trying to find if there are any pieces of software which would automatically resize images and save them in the right format for iphone and ipad... no such luck as yet!

So, I have large images of all different sizes. I need to create three images from each one.

iPad, iPhone (high res), iPhone (normal res)

I was thinking of recording something in Photoshop, but wondered if there's anything out there which already does this? My trouble is that I need to resize based on either the width or the height (which ever is larger).

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless all your graphics are rasterized it might be better to do the resizing through Photoshop, that way you don't lose the pretty vector resizing.  In Photoshop, I'd recommend checking out Export Layers to Files and Layer Comps to Files under File>Scripts. They've both proven invaluable while dealing with massive image libraries for universal apps.

Comment: this idea worked a treat! Never thought of doing it this way... the export is a little slow, but nonetheless is works nicely! thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about some batch image resizer freeware, like this?

http://www.fotosizer.com/